# Check Array elements against specific HTML element inside a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this long string of text with HTML code in it. I want to be able to check if the values inside an array match the words inside a particular element from within the string of HTML code.

Example:

```
<p>How are you</p><h2>Hello, he said fine</h2><p>But what did he know?</p><h2>So what</h2><p>Wow</p>"
```

And on the other hand, I have an array of words

```
["Hello", "Bye"]
```

What I'm trying to find, is a match between the values from the array and, in this example, the words inside the `<h2>` tags of the string with HTML text.

```
Hello --> Found!

["Hello", "Bye"] ---> Found in <h2>Hello, he said...
```

But I'm failing. Miserably. Tried like 40 different things. I'm using jQuery.

So far, this is what I have:

```
  var Array = ["Hello","Bye"];

  var RawContent = "<p>Hello how are you</p><h2>He said fine</h2><p>But what did he know?</p><h2>So what</h2><p>Wow</p>"
  
  function getData(src, filter) {
       var result = jQuery.grep(src, function (a) { return a == filter; });
       return result;
   }

  console.log(getData(RawContent, Array));
```

As it is, it does not work. I can't get the values from the H2 tags.

Can someone lend a hand? I'm confused.

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: What is your expected output? Also `Array` is a reserved keyword, don't use it as an variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#:%7E:text=The%20includes()%20method%20determines,true%20or%20false%20as%20appropriate.)() function to check for the word in your `string` that `includes` in the `array` of words.

**Searching the whole string**

**Live Demo:**

```js
var myArr= ["Hello", "Bye", "know"];

var RawContent = "<p>Hello how are you</p><h2>He said fine</h2><p>But what did he know?</p><h2>So what</h2><p>Wow</p>"

function getData(src, filter) {
  filter.forEach(function(word) {
    var result = src.includes(word)
    console.log(word + ' : ' + result) returns true if found else false 
  })
}

getData(RawContent, myArr);
```

**Searching only in `h2`**

You need to first `filter` out the `h2` `first` and then use `map()` function to get the text of your `h2` along with join() and then use `includes()` for the searching word.

**Live Demo:**

```js
var myArr = ["Hello", "said"];

var RawContent = "<p>Hello how are you</p><h2>He said fine</h2><p>But what did he know?</p><h2>So what</h2><p>Wow</p>"

function getData(src, filter) {
  var searchH2 = $(src).filter('h2').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get().join(' ');
  var result = $.grep(filter, function(word) {
    return searchH2.includes(word);
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(getData(RawContent, myArr))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's close, but... perhaps I didn't explain it well. I just needed to search within the <h2> (updating my comment)

Comment: @JavierCabrera I was about to update my answer. Please check again for searching in `<h2>`

Comment: This is the right answer and WAY too advanced for me. It will give me something to study and learn. Thanks!!!! Marking it as solved.

I'm a bit surprised that you used filter that way. To me, filter wasn't something I could just pop along with a map. Thank you for the lesson.

Comment: @JavierCabrera yes its a combination of `map` and `join` to make sure that we search the word from a string and not an array. Since map returns an `array` .Happy to help. Let me know if you have any question. I have added explanation to my answer as well :)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping  you could also supply `"h2"` as an argument so that you can use the same function for multiple html tags, see my answer for an example

Comment: What if, in this case, "said" which is a word I'm looking for, was in more than in one H2?

Comment: @JavierCabrera Includes checkes the array `h2` only once each call. If you have multiple `said` words then you would need to loop through your `searchH2` and use includes in the loop to keep two `said` words back as a result.

Answer (score 1):

**Searches throughout the string**

```js
var Array = ["Hello", "Bye"];

var RawContent = "<p>Hello how are you</p><h2>He said fine</h2><p>But what did he know?</p><h2>So what</h2><p>Wow</p>"

function getData(src, filter) {
  var result = jQuery.grep(filter, function(a) {
    return src.includes(a);
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(getData(RawContent, Array));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Searches only in `h2`**

```js
var Array = ["Hello", "Bye"];

var RawContent = "<p>Hello how are you</p><h2>He said fine</h2><p>But what did he know?</p><h2>So what</h2><p>Wow</p>"

function getData(src, filter) {
  var h2txt = $(src).filter('h2').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get().join(' ');
  
  var result = jQuery.grep(filter, function(a) {
    return h2txt.includes(a);
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(getData(RawContent, Array));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice answer. Upvoted. but a little bit of explanation will help other users to understand how the results were archived. :)

Comment: ....also its your responsibility to add some info to your answer. I can not edit people answer because they lack of details. Please consider reading how to write a good answer for other readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) and [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to get the correct strings. I turned it into a function so that you can search any html tag that you want, not only H2.

Also `Array` is a reserved keyword, don't use it as a variable name.

```js
const myArr = ["Hello", "Bye", "fine"];

const rawContent = "<p>Hello how are you</p><h2>He said fine</h2><p>But what did he know?</p><h2>So what</h2><p>Wow</p>"

const getData = (src, filters, tag) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(`<${tag}>(.*?)<\/${tag}>`, "g");
  const withinTags = src.match(regex).join("");
  
  return filters.filter((word) => withinTags.includes(word));
};

const searchedInH2 = getData(rawContent, myArr, "h2");
const searchedInP = getData(rawContent, myArr, "p");

console.log(searchedInH2);
console.log(searchedInP);
```